# How to merge array of objects A and B and form array of object C contains new key value pair?

Tags: arrays, node.js, object, arraylist, arrayobject

I am using Node.js for programming,
In the below array of Objects **A** and **B** have the arrays with have some duplicates values also, but we have to skip the duplicated for only based on **func_id** of the arrays. In the array **C** we have push both **A** and **B** **func_score** values based on **func_id** and **func_score_A** from **A(func_score)** array and **func_score_B** from **B(func_score)** array.

**Sample Code:**

```
var A = [{
    "func_id": 1,
    "func_score": 0.4
}, {
    "func_id": 2,
    "func_score": 0.5
}, {
    "func_id": 3,
    "func_score": 0.7
}];
var B = [{
    "func_id": 3,
    "func_score": 0.9
}, {
    "func_id": 4,
    "func_score": 0.7
}, {
    "func_id": 5,
    "func_score": 0.8
}];
var C = [];
var tmpArray = [];
A.forEach(function(element) {
    B.forEach(function(loop) {
        if (element.func_id === loop.func_id) {
            var tmpObje = {
                func_id: element.func_id,
                func_sore_A: element.func_score,
                func_sore_B: loop.func_score
            }
            tmpArray.push(tmpObje);
            C.push(tmpObje);
            return;
        }
    });
});

A.forEach(function(element) {
    tmpArray.forEach(function(loop) {
        if (element.func_id !== loop.func_id) {
            var smsObj = {
                func_id: element.func_id,
                func_sore_A: element.func_score,
                func_sore_B: 0
            }
            C.push(smsObj);
            return;
        }
    });
});

B.forEach(function(element) {
    tmpArray.forEach(function(loop) {
        if (element.func_id !== loop.func_id) {
            var domineObj = {
                func_id: element.func_id,
                func_sore_A: 0,
                func_sore_B: loop.func_score
            }
            C.push(domineObj);
            return;
        }
    });
});
console.log(C);
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
{"func_id": 1, 
"func_score_A": 0.4,
"func_score_B":0
}, 
{"func_id": 2, 
"func_score_A": 0.5,
"func_score_B":0
},
{"func_id": 3, 
"func_score_A": 0.7,
"func_score_B":0.9
},
{"func_id": 4, 
"func_score_A": 0,
"func_score_B":0.7
},
{"func_id": 5, 
"func_score_A": 0,
"func_score_B":0.8
}
]
```

**Note:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that might be a little simpler.

```js
var A = [{
    "func_id": 1,
    "func_score": 0.4
}, {
    "func_id": 2,
    "func_score": 0.5
}, {
    "func_id": 3,
    "func_score": 0.7
}];

var B = [{
    "func_id": 3,
    "func_score": 0.9
}, {
    "func_id": 4,
    "func_score": 0.7
}, {
    "func_id": 5,
    "func_score": 0.8
}];

let C = A.map(e => {
    return {
        func_id: e.func_id,
        func_score_A: e.func_score,
        func_score_B: 0
    };
});
B.forEach(e => {
    let i = C.findIndex(x => x.func_id == e.func_id);
    if (i >= 0) {
        C[i].func_score_B = e.func_score;
    } else {
        C.push({
            func_id: e.func_id,
            func_score_A: 0,
            func_score_B: e.func_score
        })
    }
});
console.log(C);
```

Comment: Hi Jim B , Your approach working fine like exactly what i want. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is quite simple, first replace all `sore` with `score`. Then in your `B.forEach()` loop, you possibly made the mistake of taking `loop.func_score` instead of `element.func_score`.

```
B.forEach(function(element) {
    tmpArray.forEach(function(loop) {
        if (element.func_id !== loop.func_id) {
            var domineObj = {
                func_id: element.func_id,
                func_sore_A: 0,
                // loop should be element
                // func_sore_B: loop.func_score
                func_sore_B: element.func_score
            }
            C.push(domineObj);
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi ssemilla, even i changed the code as per you suggestion but still i didn't  get Expected Output but,below another guy Mr Jim given another little simpler approach , its working fine. Any way thank you for your stuff.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this without all the code below just do `var C = A.concat(B)`

```
var A = [{
    "func_id": 1,
    "func_score": 0.4
}, {
    "func_id": 2,
    "func_score": 0.5
}, {
    "func_id": 3,
    "func_score": 0.7
}];
var B = [{
    "func_id": 3,
    "func_score": 0.9
}, {
    "func_id": 4,
    "func_score": 0.7
}, {
    "func_id": 5,
    "func_score": 0.8
}];

//check the console for output
console.log(A.concat(B));
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/1e304w7t/

Comment: Hi Rick ,A.concat(B) is not correct solution, Kindly see the Expected Output